# Автоматическая авторизация в лаунчере игры

Tags: bat, автоматизация

Есть лаунчер игры (PUBG Lite, например).
Возможно ли автоматизировать авторизацию в лаунчере с помощью командной строки?
Если нет возможности реализовать это через .bat-файл, есть ли иные способы реализации?

Comment: Если лаунчер управляем через командную строку (передача аргументов процессу), то вы можете автоматизировать авторизацию. Если нет, то нужно разрабатывать свой лаунчер, который это будет уметь.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) можно отправлять сигналы нажатия клавиатуры и мыши по нужным вам окнам в нужный момент времени.

Answer (score 0):

Есть прекрасная программа [nncron](http://www.nncron.ru/index_ru.shtml), бесплатная для некоммерческого использования. Вообще ее основное предназначение - планировщик. Но зарегистрированная задача может быть исполнена интерактивно из меню, вызываемого иконкой в трейбаре. Запуск процессов - это 1% от возможностей программы, а то и меньше. Размер установленной программы 2Mb, размер используемой памяти запущенного процесса 0.5Mb.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все манипуляции с поиском окон, передвижением указателя мыши. кликами, эмуляции клавиатурного ввода поддерживаются "из-коробки". Есть встроенный язык автоматизации на основе Forth.